# Python flask wont render multiple templates, possibly HTML issue

Tags: python, html, css, linux, flask

Updated question: my flask web page is working well, however i am currently editing my 3rd page and its doing something i cant understand. when i click on the third tab of my web app, the URL goes localhost/DC2/DC5, whereas i need it to go localhost/DC5. Im not sure why its jumping through the first page. Here is my flask & the part of my HTML code which i think may be causing this:

```
<li><a href="/">Homepage</a></li>
<li><a href="DC2">DC2</a></li>
<li class="current_page_item"><a href="/DC5/">DC5</a></li>
<li><a href="Supra">Supra</a></li>
<li><a href="S13">S13</a></li>
<li><a href="S15">S15</a></li>
<li><a href="Chaser">Chaser</a></li>
```

and here is my flask:

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, abort
app = Flask(**name**)

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
  return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/DC2/")
def DC2():
  return render_template('DC2.html')

@app.route("/DC5/")
def DC5():
  return render_template('DC5.html')

@app.route("/Supra/")
def Supra():
  return render_template('Supra.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
```

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We don't know what clicking DC2 does. What is the address where it gives the error? Is it missing a slash at the end by any chance?

Also don't use images to show code.

Comment: Paste the code into the quesion. Don't put a screenshot of it.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40207590/edit) your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Post your Jinja2 template. Are you hardcoding URLs instead of using `url_for()`?

Comment: Correct, i am hardcoding as you can see in the post, i am not using jinja2. Rather than have to edit all my files i was wondering if theres a simple fix to this? Thanks.

Comment: @Trekky: Jinja2 would be the simple fix. You hardcoded the wrong URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your links are relative to the current page. If you're at `/DC5/` and click on `<a href="S13">S13</a>`, you'll end up at `/DC5/S13`, not `/S13`. You could fix this by making your URLs absolute:

```
<a href="/S13">S13</a>
```

Although that's a temporary fix. An easier way to do this would be to use [`url_for`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.url_for):

```
<a href="{{ url_for('S13') }}">S13</a>
```

Comment: Works both ways. You my friend have solved something which has held me back for hours.